# Как сериализовать UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, сериализация, usercontrol

Я пытаюсь сериализовать с помощью `BinaryFormatter` кастомный объект, который выглядит как то так:

```
[Serializable]
    public partial class DbTable : UserControl
    {
        public List<DbTable> Connections { get; set; }

        public List<DbTableItem> Attributes { get; set; }

        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }

        public DbTable(string tableName, List<DbTableItem> attrs, List<DbTable> connections, Point position)
        {
            ...
        }
        
        ...

    }


    [Serializable]
    public sealed class DbTableItem
    {
        ...
    }
```

но при попытке сериализации получаю следующее исключение:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Тип "System.Windows.Controls.UserControl" в сборке "PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" не помечен как сериализуемый.'
```

Нашел информацию, что это исключение возникает при наличии в объекте ссылок на объекты, не помеченные как сериализуемые, и что лучше для сериализации создать модель объекта по которой можно воссоздать его.

Но как создать модель объекта `DbTable`, если эта модель должна включать свойство `Connections`, которое содержит ссылку на другой объект `DbTable`?

Comment: `DbTable : UserControl` - это неправильно, да и вообще, зачем вам это? WPF, это про отделение интерфейса от логики, а у вас все в одну кашу получается. Сделайте отдельный класс для сериализации, пусть это будет простой DTO объект, без какой-либо логики, пусть он служит только для передачи данных, не более.

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` на сегодняшний день уже признан мёртвым, и уже в .NET 6 будет выпилен из фреймворка окончательно. Дайте ему покоиться с миром. Используйте для сериализации например Newtonsoft.Json, если вы на Framework 4.х или System.Text.Json, если на Core 3.1 или новее. И да, вынесите данные в отдельный класс. И если еще не читали, почитацте про то, что такое MVVM для WPF.

Comment: @aepot И это не правильно, как ещё сериализовать с максимальным сжатием?

Comment: @Blackmeser ручками через BinaryWriter. Байт еще меньше получится, чем у форматтера, раза в полтора. Ну можно еще в Json и в gzip. На что фантазии хватит.

Comment: Если сериализуется список/массив, а число объектов десятки/сотни, или того больше, выигрыш несущественный, а сложность сериализации/десериализации для того кто пишет код - выше. В конце-концов BinaryWriter не сериализатор, а просто коробка для примитивного метода разложения на байты и записи в поток.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По рекомендации [EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz) и [aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot) создал модель для DbTable, которую и сериализовывал.

Итоговый код:

```
    public partial class DbTable : UserControl
    {
        public DbTableData TableData { get; set; }

        public DbTable(DbTableData tableModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.TableData = tableModel;
            
            ...

        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DbTableData
    {
        public List<DbTableData> Connections { get; set; }

        public List<DbTableItem> Attributes { get; set; }

        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class DbTableItem
    {
        ...


    }
```